# OpenShift Build Config Image pull issue

Tags: docker, kubernetes, openshift

I am using a build config to create a docker image and push to private artifactory.

The build yaml pull the source code from Git, and the source strategy I mentioned is Dockerfile which is inside the git repo.

Below is my build YAML

```
kind: BuildConfig
apiVersion: build.openshift.io/v1
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: >
     openshift.io/generated-by: OpenShiftNewApp
  resourceVersion: '1879164387'
  name: employee-service
spec:
  nodeSelector: null
  output:
    to:
      kind: DockerImage
      name: >-
        privateregistry.abc.com/namespace-abc/empservice:20232703
    pushSecret:
      name: private-registry-secret
  resources:
    limits:
      memory: 1Gi
  successfulBuildsHistoryLimit: 5
  failedBuildsHistoryLimit: 5
  strategy:
    type: Docker
    dockerStrategy:
      dockerfilePath: Dockerfile
  postCommit: {}
  source:
    type: Git
    git:
      uri: >-
        http://git.abc.com:8080/tfs/_git/emp-service
      ref: development
    sourceSecret:
      name: empgitsecret
  runPolicy: Serial
status:
  lastVersion: 11
```

In the above build YAML,

I am pulling a repository using the secret "empgitsecret"
I have specified the strategy type as docker which is a dockerfile in the repository.

The problem is inside the docker file there is a reference to an image that pulls from private artifactory  which is throwing an error

"failed to pull image: After retrying 2...uthorized: The client does not have permission for manifest"

Comment: You will need to add a pull secret to your configuration. This is covered [in the documentation](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.9/cicd/builds/creating-build-inputs.html#builds-docker-credentials-private-registries_creating-build-inputs).

Comment: If I mention a pull secret it is not accepting, I mean the yaml does not get saved,  In the yaml I used SourceStrategy as type docker and mentioned dockerfile name, I believe it looks into the repo

Comment: Have you linked your secret to the builder service account? `oc secrets link builder <your secret>`

Comment: Thank you, linking the secret worked